# Bootstrap scroll table break when fix head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to fix the table header when scrolling. And the rest of the page content to scroll. But the original layout of the table breaks. The width of the table columns and rows is of different size. I am not able to fix this.

My code:

HTML

```
<section class="scrollable padder">
<table class="table table-striped m-b-none text-sm m-t">
<thead class="ff">
<tr>
    <th >1col</th>
    <th >2col</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="new_td">field1</td>
        <td class="new_td">field2</td>
    </td>
</tbody>
</table>
</section>
```

JS

```
    $(".padder").scroll(function() {
    if ($(".padder").scrollTop() > 100) {
             $('.ff').addClass('fixed');
            }
            else
    {
     $('.ff').removeClass('fixed');
     }
    });
```

CSS

```
.fixed{    
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;   
}
```

Comment: may be some tag closing issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 table with fixed header and scrolling table body doesn't let tbody scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483320/bootstrap-4-table-with-fixed-header-and-scrolling-table-body-doesnt-let-tbody-s)

Answer (score 0):

try this tag and let me know the result

```
<section class="scrollable padder">
    <table class="table table-striped m-b-none text-sm m-t">
    <thead class="ff">
    <tr>
        <th >1col</th>
        <th >2col</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="new_td">field1</td>
            <td class="new_td">field2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement using this:

```
<table id="fixed"></table>
```

Css

```
#fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0px; display:none;
background-color:white;
}
```

Js

```
var $fix= $(".table > thead").clone();
var $hfxd = $("#fixed").append($fix);
$(".padder").scroll(function() {
if ($(".padder").scrollTop() > 100 && $fix.is(":hidden")) 
{
   $hfxd.show();
 }
 else
 {
 $hfxd.hide();
 }
});
```